# ¿ Cómo hacer un setter a partir de una imagen obtenida con glide url?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-glide

Estoy tratando de mostrar una imagen obtenida mediante una url con la librería glide, la imagen la muestro en el recyclerview, todo bien si problemas, tengo implementado un longclick al momento de usar la propiedad longclick me muestra los valores respectivos de cada columna del recyclerview pero no he logrado mostrar la imagen, solo texto, quería saber si hay alguna forma de mostrar la imagen obtenida desde glide en el fragmento sin usar la propiedad de carga de imágenes de glide ya que se tendría que volver a cargar la imagen y no es lo correcto.

Necesito mostrar la imagen en el dialogo que se despliega en LongClick, sin cargar nuevamente la imagen con glide.

**adaptador**

```
Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(appointment.getmImage())
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .override(350, 130)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            //.bitmapTransform(new RoundedCornersTransformation(mContext, 10, 0))
            .into(holder.imagee);

    holder.imagee.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    holder.imagee.buildDrawingCache();
    bitmap = holder.imagee.getDrawingCache();
```

**fragment.java**

```
public void onRowLongClicked(int position) {
            dialogo(position);
        }
    });


 //compartir longclick
public void  dialogo(int position) {
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    final View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog_compartir, null);
    final android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable (true);
    TextView  titulo = (TextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.titulodialogo);
    TextView comentariocompartir = (TextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.comentariodialogo);
    ImageView imagencompartir = (ImageView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.imgwork2);
    imagee = (ImageView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.imgwork);
    Button btnshared =  (Button) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.entrar_boton);
    Button btncancel =  (Button) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);
    String add,add1;
    AppointmentDisplayList callpojo = adapter.get(position);
    callpojo.setRead(true);
    adapter.set(position, callpojo);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    if (mAdapter.getSelectedItemCount() > 1) {
        enableActionMode(position);
    } else {
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(callpojo.getmNombre_v())){

            add = callpojo.getmNombre_v()+" ";
        } else{
            add = "";
        }
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(callpojo.getmNombre_acto())){
            add1 = callpojo.getmNombre_acto()+" ";
        } else{
            add1 = "";
        }
        titulo.setText(add+add1+callpojo.getTitle());
        comentariocompartir.setText(callpojo.getmContent());
    }
    enableActionMode(position);
 /*   Glide.with(getActivity())
            .load(callpojo.getmImage())
            .fitCenter()
            .into(imagencompartir);*/

       Bitmap  bm = mAdapter.bitmap;
      imagencompartir.setImageBitmap(bm);
    if  (callpojo.getmImage().equals(""))  {
        imagencompartir.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        imagencompartir.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "no nula "+callpojo.getmImage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    final android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    btnshared.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mAdapter.clearSelections();
            mAdapter.resetAnimationIndex();
            alertDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    btncancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mAdapter.clearSelections();
            mAdapter.resetAnimationIndex();
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }

    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Puedes volver a cargarla, glide usara la imagen en memoria, y cache sin descargarla nuevamente.

Comment: okey pues esa no la sabia, estoy utilizando este atributo   .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)  , no hay problema por eso

Comment: Ninguno, glide tiene distintos tipos de cache, NONE no almacenara nada en cache, SOURCE almacena la imagen original, con el tamaño original, RESULT almacenara la imagen final incluso si la has redimensionado y por ultimo ALL deja en cache todas. Asi que usa glide sin problema, no es mala practica.